# Macro to reverse a sequenece of parenthesized tokens?

Tags: c++, macros

What I'm trying to do boils down to:

```
#define REVERSER ??? //what should this be?
REVERSER(foo)(int) //evaluates to "int foo"
```

I've been trying and trying to figure out a way to do this, but I'm not having any luck. Any known solutions?

**Edit for the curious:**

```
JAVA_CLASS(MyClass, com.example.MyClass) {
    JavaString JAVA_METHOD(someMethod)(JavaClass foo, int bar);
}
```

JAVA_METHOD would take (someMethod) and expand into another macro that would consume (JavaClass foo, int bar). I'm almost there, but it looks like I'll have to use

```
JavaString JAVA_METHOD((someMethod)(JavaClass foo, int bar));
```

instead

Comment: #define REVERSER(x,y) y x

Comment: @jarmod The parameters are separated by parenthesis (instead of commas), like a boost sequence, but without being wrapped in another level of parenthesis. That isn't a working solution.

Comment: Then your problem is not making REVERSER. It is making your parameters come (from wherever they are coming from) in the form of comma separated instead of parens separated.

Comment: Doubt that flies with the pre-processor.  You could do it with a text processing step before compilation, of course.  Convert the source prior to compilation using sed/awk, store it in a temporary folder, and compile that instead of the golden source.

Comment: What is the underlying problem that you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: It's a whopper. I'm making a library that almost entirely eliminates the boiler plate of using JNI. You can make a C++ proxy class using nearly-c++ syntax, and it automatically handles JNIEnv, marhsalling data types, etc. Since it's c++ only, it is needless to say that it is composed of many files of template and macro magic.

Comment: @Brent: You'll have to be more clear about the technical problem you're trying to solve.  This type of transformation is just not something suitable for the C++ preprocessor -- you'll either need to use some other preprocessor (e.g. GNU m4 or custom awk/sed/other script; makefiles might ease the pain on this a bit)) or restructure your problem into something more amenable to the C++ preprocessor.

Comment: OK. That's what I suspected. The c++-like syntax will have to be just a little bit less c++ like. That's ok though.

Comment: Edited the question to show what I'm actually trying to accomplish.